# How to generate a random integers vector that sums up to a given number in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe `my_df` and I would like to add an additional column, `my_new_column`, and populate it with random integer numbers that add up to a given sum.
Here is some reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
my_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 2))
colnames(my_df) <- c("Cat", "MarksA")
my_df$Cat <- LETTERS[1:nrow(my_df)]
my_df$MarksA <- sample(1:100, size = nrow(my_df))
```

In `Tidyverse` style, I tried the following:

```
my_df %<>% mutate(my_new_column=sample(n()))
```

However, this gives me a column which sums up to an arbitrary number. How can I tweak my code to achieve this task?

Comment: `sample(n())` is equivalent to `sample(nrow(my_df))` which is equivalent to `sample(1:nrow(my_df))` for your info

Comment: You may want to look at a way to make a parttion of an integer in R : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partitions/vignettes/partitionspaper.pdf

Comment: I don't see what the first two columns of the dataframe brings

Comment: @Julien can you help me solve this using this package you're suggesting? I checked its vignette and it's very terse for my level.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify a specific distribution, would this work? I pulled my answer mostly from this post which has more details and more options: [Generate non-negative (or positive) random integers that sum to a fixed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559455/generate-non-negative-or-positive-random-integers-that-sum-to-a-fixed-value)

```
my_df %>%
  mutate(int_sample = rmultinom(n = 1, size = 1000, prob = rep.int(1 / 10, 10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the sum of all numbers between 1 and `n` is equal to `n(n + 1)/2`, you may try something like this :

```r
nb <- nrow(my_df)
my_df %<>% mutate(my_new_column = sample(nb * (nb + 1)/2))
```